# How to handle success message to fill up on listview in android using retrofit 1.9.0?

Tags: android, json, listview, retrofit

how to handle json response in retrofit version 1.9.0

1. how to set into listview using that
2. Like this image show

   https://i.stack.imgur.com/RIu8Y.png

Comment: is this by POST method or GET mothod?

Comment: this is get method.